# PHP included header is not updated

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, browser-cache, php-include

I don't even know how to name this question because this is the weirdest thing that happened to me. I have an index.php and it includes several headers:

```
<?php
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/config.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/lang.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/logs.php';
    // crazy header here
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/info.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/security.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/database.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/visitor.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/content.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/inc/devel.php';
?>
```

Each one of these is nicely included and everything is fine. When, inside the `devel.php` script I call `get_included_files()` I can see all of them included. Also, each of them echoes a message. Cool.

1. Now I just added a new header called `standard.php` between `logs.php` and `info.php`.  It contains this simple code:

   `<?php echo "Standard included"; ?>`
2. Despite being successfully included (`get_included_files()` shows it) I don't see the message. Weird, very weird.
3. Now, I delete it and create a new one called `test.php`. It is included and shows the message *Test Included*.
4. Now, I rename it to *standard.php* and it works. I still see the message *Test Included*.
5. I decide to change the message to *Standard Included* but surprise: the message shown is still *Test Included*.
6. I delete everything and leave only `<?php ?>` in the script but I still see only the message *Test Included*. Is like PHP got crazy and keeps it in some cache.
7. But wait, I rename the file to `test2.php` (still empty) and I still see the same message. This is like Paranormal Activity, the message is haunting me now. As long as I include a new header in the list above I get that message.

I have **WAMP** installed and everything happens on **localhost**. What could be the problem? I restarted Apache and still the same issue.

Comment: OK. The issue is not WAMP. It is piece of crap Notepad++, that can't update the file properly. If this happens to you make sure your shi**y editor is not screwing you up like this.

Comment: so paranormal activity ended at last :)